# Scrollable menu using MenuItem's

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

What I am trying to accomplish with Cocos2d, is to create a horizontal menu, which can be swiped from left to right. I posted an image, to show my idea.

The image below has a white bar, where I want to show MenuItem objects, now I want to be able to do a swipe in the white region, so that the next menu item is centered.

[Example http://www.wimhaanstra.com/images/MenuExample.png](http://www.wimhaanstra.com/images/MenuExample.png)

The problem I am facing is, I would really like to use the Menu (& MenuItem) functionality of Cocos2d, but it seems somehow that the MenuItem object does not accept touches other than just tapping it. Also I want the swipe to be detected not only on the MenuItem, but the whole white bar.

What would be the best approach for this?

- Somehow incorporate an UIScrollView, but that would be a shame, because I would like to use OpenGL for everything
- Subclasss the MenuItem class, to create one where the ccTouchBegan is handled, and somehow move the whole Menu?
- Just leave the whole Menu idea behind, and replace the Menu and MenuItems with sprites  which support touching.

I read somewhere that MenuItem's shouldn't really be used for this kind of work, but why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layer can handle touches event.
you can put you menuItems into one layer.

detect a swipe, and move the the menuItems

Comment: there is a post about Looping/Scrolling Menu, that is cool. and some source codes by Joao Caxaria. You change some code to control the item position.
Hope it helps. 
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/139