# Sliding a CCMenu

Tags: cocoa, cocos2d-iphone

I have a Menu ("myMenu") containing `CCMenuItemImage`s. I would like this menu to detect finger swipes and slide accordingly.

My problem is that the `CCMenuItemImage`s seem to absorb the touch event. The swipe works fine when the user touches the menu outside of the CCMenuItemImages, but not when the touch happens on these.

I have tried to put my menu items in a layer to detect touches (refering to answer [Scrollable menu using MenuItem's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973755/scrollable-menu-using-menuitems)), but this doesn't seem to work either. Any idea why ?

```
+(id) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    ModeMenuScene *layer = [ModeMenuScene node];
    [scene addChild: layer];
    return scene;
}

-(id) init
{
    if( (self=[super init] )) {


        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"bg.png"];
        background.position=ccp(winSize.width/2,winSize.height/2);
        [self addChild:background];

        mode1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Mode1.png" selectedImage: @"Mode1.png" target:self selector:@selector(goToMode1:)];
        mode1label = [CCLabelTTF labelWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level 1 %d", n] dimensions:CGSizeMake(220,53) alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter fontName:@"Arial" fontSize:20.0];
        mode1label.color = ccc3(167,0,0);
        mode1label.position=ccp(55,-30);
        [mode1 addChild:mode1label];

    // here same kind of code to define mode2,mode3,mode4 (taken out to reduce size of code)

        myMenu=[CCMenu menuWithItems:mode1,mode2,mode3,mode4,nil];
        [myMenu alignItemsHorizontallyWithPadding:25];
        myMenu.position=ccp(winSize.width/2+40,180);
        menuLayer = [CCLayer node];
        [menuLayer addChild:myMenu];
        [self addChild:menuLayer];

        [self enableTouch];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) disableTouch{
    self.isTouchEnabled=NO;
    menuLayer.isTouchEnabled=NO;
}

-(void) enableTouch{
    self.isTouchEnabled=YES;
    menuLayer.isTouchEnabled=YES;
}


-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    if(location.y>100 && location.y<260) {
        draggingMenu=1;
        x_initial = location.x;
    }
    else draggingMenu=0;
}


-(void) ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:[touch view]];
    if(draggingMenu==1) {
        CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        int x = myMenu.position.x+location.x-x_initial;
        x = MAX(0,x);
        x = MIN(x,winSize.width/2+40);
        myMenu.position=ccp(x,180);
        x_initial=location.x;
    }
}

- (void) ccTouchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    draggingMenu=0;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it by adding :

```
-(void) registerWithTouchDispatcher
{
    [[CCTouchDispatcher sharedDispatcher] addTargetedDelegate:self priority:INT_MIN+1 swallowsTouches:NO];
}
```

the problem was that CCMenuItemImage swallows the touches and has a high priority set at -128. Thus the need to set priority at `INT_MIN+1`

Comment: Where did you add this code ? I am also stuck to the same point ?

Comment: In the CCScene class that contains the CCMenuItemImages